# How to smooth subtitle fonts in SMPlayer?

Tags: 12.04, mplayer

How to smooth subtitle fonts in SMPlayer in Ubuntu 12.04. I prefer a solution for SMplayer. When the movie is playing subtitle fonts are blurry and pixelized.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. I have removed your secondary question about VLC. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After a while I found a solution to this:

In Smplayer Preferences->General->Video Tab choose for Output driver: opengl or gl, instead of Default or xv